# Highest "Valued" Palindrome

Tags: java, c, algorithm

So I was at a programming interview a few months ago and this problem tripped me up for some reason. There are a couple of solutions I can think of but most of them seem extremely inefficient. Though I've been programming in some capacity for years, I'm currently in college for a CS degree so my point of reference may be incomplete. I was hoping someone here might offer up some possible solutions:

"Given a set of strings and associated numerical 'values,' assemble a palindrome from these string whose value (defined by the sum of the strings used to create it) is the highest possible."

There were no limits to how many strings could be provided, some strings may not be used.

Example:
"asd" - 3
"dsa" - 5
"appa" - 1

Result would be "asdappadsa" with a value of 9.

My thought would be to try all strings in all orders, then drop off one, starting with the lowest valued one, but that solution is O(N!) and I'd assume that's not ok.

(Preferred languages are C and Java, but whatever works)

EDIT: Clarification. Each string provided can only be used once, and has to be used exactly as provided, though you may choose to not use any of the strings in your palindrome. You can not use substrings of provided strings, nor can you reverse the string.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can append as many strings as you want to form this palindrome, or...?

Comment: As I understand it you can use each string at most once, right?

Comment: @kostyan I don't see how this would produce the same result, since "ddsa" is not a substring of the result in the post.  A more interesting question would be, should "asda, "ppad", "sa" produce the same result.

Comment: @ajb you're right, wanted to ask what you've illustrated with your example

Comment: I think you're right about the O(N!) bit, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

Replace "all strings" with "all palindromes" and the problem space becomes much smaller.

Divide the strings into 26 subsets.

```
 Strings beginning with x (for 'a' <= x <= 'z')  
   [or whatever the set of "letters" is]
```

Now divide them into another 26 subsets

```
 Strings ending with y ( for 'a' <= y <= 'z')
```

Note each string appears in a "begins with" set and an "ends with" set.

Use these sets to guide creation of all possible palindromes.

```
 Start with two empty strings:  prefix and suffix
 for each string in the original set
    assign it to the prefix
    call recursiveFunction(prefix, suffix)

 def recursiveFunction(prefix, suffix):
    if prefix + <anything> + suffix cannot form a palindrome return
    if prefix + suffix is a palindrome, remember it
    while you have unused strings
      if the suffix is shorter than the prefix
           Look at the first unmatched character in the prefix
           for each unused string that ends in that character
              call recursiveFunction(prefix, string + suffix)

      else if prefix is shorter than suffix
         look at the last unmatched character in the suffix
            for each unused string that ends with that character
               call recursiveFunction(prefix + string, suffix)
      else // suffix and prefix have equal lenghths
         for each unused string
           call recursiveFunction(prefix + string, suffix)
```

Be sure to mark the string used in both begins with and ends when you use it.
And be sure to consider the impact of recursion on the "used" marker.

Then pick the palindrome with the best score.

Comment: I'm I right in saying that this would have exponential worst-case performance (which would happen when all the strings start and end with the same character)?

Comment: Worse case -> All strings are made up of the same character.   Yes, that would be O(N!), but my intuition says average performance should be much better.  Anyone want to do a formal analysis to prove or disprove that?

Comment: I'm going to look into coding this up in some form in the next couple of days to see where it gets me.

Comment: Not really understanding why line one in the recursive function is there, could you explain when you get a sec?

Comment: The first line of the recursive function is what reduces the problem space  if you have   ABC...AA then adding new string in the middle cannot possibly produce a palindrome, but if you have ABC...BA then there's hope so the search continues

Comment: And the second line detects something like ABCC....BA and emits ABCCBA as one possible palindrome, but continues to search for longer ones.

Answer (score 0):

With palindrones, you can split the string into 3 substrings, ABC.  There is potential within the set to find string reversals, so when you get a hit you can keep track of these strings for useage in substring A and C.  If you don't get a reversal hit within the entire set, you just need to find the largest string (or string with the highest value) that is a reflection of itself.  Not the best solution, I'm sure, but I did it for fun anyways so I may as well share.  Also, I made no efforts to make this code "clean", so its a bit ugly, but it works.

```
public class Main {

    private static String[] set = new String[] { "asdf" , "kjdij", "skjdihi", "ddidid" , "ididid", "iddid", "oihu", "uhio", "fdsa", "ajsja" };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Used for a couple of for loops...
        int count;

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(); //Hold the strings and their reversals in a hashmap for quick lookups.

        /* Think of the palindrome as 3 substrings, A, B, and C. */
        ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> B = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        ArrayList<String> C = new ArrayList<String>();


        count = set.length;
        String[] reverse_set = new String[count];
        for(int x = 0; x < count; x++){

            String reverse = new StringBuilder(set[x]).reverse().toString();

            /* Check strings that would work for section B, since it's a set, we know that if it could work for B, 
             * it couldn't work for A or C - since a set contains no duplicates. */
             if(reverse.equals(set[x])){
                 B.add(set[x]);
             } else {
                 /* Otherwise, we'll have to check to see if it would work for A and C */
                 reverse_set[x] = reverse;
                 map.put(set[x], reverse);               
             }

        }

        /* Check the map for reverse string hits, we know that if another string exists in set S such that S(X) == R(X) it can work for substring
         * A and C. */
        int map_size = map.size();
            int hit_count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < map_size; i++){
            String s = map.get(reverse_set[i]);
            if(s != null){
                            hit_count++;
                A.add(set[i]);
                C.add(reverse_set[i]);
                map.remove(set[i]);  //remove the reflection, so we don't get duplicates
            }
        }

        /* Find the longest string in B, since we'll have to do this even if was had any hits in the previous loop. */
        String b = null;
        if(B.size() > 0){
            int length = 0;
            for(String x : B){
                int mLength = x.length();
                if(mLength > length){
                    b = x;
                    length = mLength;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Build the palinedrome */
        String palineString = "";
        if(hit_count == 0 && b != null){
            palineString = b;
        } else {
            for(String x : A){
                palineString += x;
            }
            if(b != null){
                palineString += b;
            }
            count = C.size();
            for(int y = (count - 1); y >= 0; y--){
                palineString += C.get(y); 
            }
        }

        if(checkPalindrome(palineString)){
            System.out.print("The Palindrone is: " + palineString + " Score: " + Integer.toString(palineString.length()));
        } else {
            System.out.print("Oops...");
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkPalindrome(String x){
        if(x.equals(new StringBuilder(x).reverse().toString())){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
The Palindrone is: asdfoihuajsjauhiofdsa Score: 21
```

EDIT:

Note: for the time being, I used the string's length as the "assigned value", I'll make an edit later to account for assigning random values to strings, but it won't make too much of a difference, since it only adds a few extra use cases to check for.

Comment: Thing is, you have 45 minutes to be presented the question, code it on a whiteboard, and go over test cases. Seems overly complicated for that time span?

Comment: I did it in about 30, so I don't see how writing it with suedo code would be any harder.